# Foursquare API: sort checkins by oldest first

Tags: foursquare

So I have some code that's been running for a good ~6 months or so, and I don't *think* I've changed anything relevant to this (famous last developer words), but Foursquare has started returning what I'd consider to be incorrect responses.

I'm trying to hit the checkins endpoint for yourself: i.e., `/v2/users/self/checkins`. My options params are as follows:

```
params = {
  v: '20160622',
  afterTimestamp: start_time,
  sort: 'oldestfirst',
  limit: 250
}
```

This all seems to be fine and dandy, but Foursquare is only seemingly sub-sorting newest-first. In other words, I'm asking Foursquare for "show me all of the checkins, sorted by the oldest" and it's returning stuff from today. Especially with `afterTimestamp: 0`, I expect that it should show me the *oldest* checkin associated with my account: namely, my very first checkin of all time.

So, to recap: how do I query the API so that I can find my oldest checkins first? From what I can tell, this *should* be properly returning the correct checkins.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this endpoint and it appears to sort results after they're extracted from "most recent". So in your case it's taking the most recent 250 checkins *then* sorting them by oldest first.

To get your first checkin ever you can look at the `count` of checkins that gets returned then `offset` by that amount. After you've got your first checkin you can work forwards with the `afterTimestamp` parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid that since I'm pretty sure I wasn't doing that before, but sighhhhh.

Anyway, this doesn't seem to work either: `After you've got your first checkin you can work forwards with the afterTimestamp parameter.` I can't use `afterTimestamp={my-earliest-timestamp}` to get anything *but* my most recent checkins first (instead of ones from seven years ago). Maybe they really do have a bug in their API?

Comment: Actually on second thought, I think the integer offset approach still works for an initial import. So I guess I'll have to do that to initially import a user's checkins, and then use a different approach for incremental imports (likely the realtime endpoint anyway). Quite a bit more code, but I guess that's how their API works now.